CGAL Arrangement Segment Traits typedef in subclass not overriding typedef in parent
I have a custom subclass of CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2:
 template <typename Kernel_ = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel>
class K_VisArr_segment;

template <typename Kernel_ = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel>
class K_VisArr_segment_traits : public CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel_> {
    
    friend class K_VisArr_segment<Kernel_>;
 
public:
    typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel_> Superclass;

    typedef typename Kernel_::Point_2        Point_2;
    typedef  K_VisArr_segment<Kernel_>           X_monotone_curve_2;
    typedef  K_VisArr_segment<Kernel_>           Curve_2;
};

template <typename Kernel_>
class K_VisArr_segment : public K_VisArr_segment_traits<Kernel_>::_Segment_cached_2 {

    typedef typename K_VisArr_segment_traits<Kernel_>::_Segment_cached_2 Base;
    typedef typename Kernel_::Segment_2                               Segment_2;
    typedef typename Kernel_::Point_2                                 Point_2;
    typedef typename Kernel_::Line_2                                  Line_2;
    private:
        int id_;
    public:
        
        
        K_VisArr_segment(const typename Segment_2& seg) : Base(seg) {
            this.id_ = seg.id();
        }

        int id() const { return id_; }

        int& id() { return id_; }

        
};

however my typedefs in the subclass 'K_VisArr_segment_traits' don't seem to be overriding the typedefs in the parent class. Snippet of CGAL parent class:
template <typename Kernel_ = Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel>
class Arr_segment_2;

template <typename Kernel_ = Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel>
class Arr_segment_traits_2 : public Kernel_ {
  friend class Arr_segment_2<Kernel_>;
public:
  // Traits objects
  typedef typename Kernel::Point_2        Point_2;
  typedef Arr_segment_2<Kernel>           X_monotone_curve_2;
  typedef Arr_segment_2<Kernel>           Curve_2;
  typedef unsigned int                    Multiplicity;

I use the traits class like this:
using MK = typename K_Vis_Kernel<FT>;

using Traits = typename K_VisArr_segment_traits<MK>;
using Arrangement = CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits>;

but I get the error
'CGAL::Sign CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel_>::Compare_y_at_x_2::operator ()(const CGAL::Point_2<Kernel_> &,const CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> &) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const K_VisArr_segment<Kernel_>' to 'const CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> &'
So, it looks like the compare function is still using the old version of X_monotone_curve_2. Snippet of CGAL comapre function in Arr_traits_adaptor_2.h:
Comparison_result compare_y_at_x(const Point_2& p,
                                 const X_monotone_curve_2& xcv,
                                 Arr_all_sides_oblivious_tag,
                                 Arr_all_sides_oblivious_tag) const {
  const Base& base = m_self;
  auto cmp_y_at_x = base.compare_y_at_x_2_object();
  return cmp_y_at_x(p, xcv);
}

As far as I know typedefs in subclasses should replace the typedefs in the parent. Is there something I'm doing wrong that's preventing it from happening?

Typedefs in a derived class redefine the types in the derived class, but not in the base class. You need to use a mechanism similar to the extensible kernel mechanism; see https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#title20, or redefine the functors in the derived class.
